# How to print the same char n times in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I would like to print a char underlining a String n times, with n the length of the String in Haskell.

How should I do this?

My String is: "Available Chars (x)" 
and I want to have a char underlining that sentence, which should have exactly the same length as the "Available Chars (x)". But x is an int, so it could be "1" or "10" or "1000" etc.. so the length is variable.  I got the length but i didnt know how to print that char as long as the string is...

Comment: See the `replicate` function, and note that a `String` is just a synonym for `[Char]`

Comment: I saw it, but I couldnt find any example to see how to really use it... :(

Comment: @ZelelB It's very basic, so if you stumble on something like that, maybe you should [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:replicate):

```
underline :: String -> String
underline = flip replicate '-' . length
```

This will give you a string which is n times the character '-' where n is the length of the input string. It is the same as:

```
underline = map (const '-')
```

You can then use it like this (if for example `yourString = "Available Chars (111)"`):

```
> putStrLn yourString >> putStrLn (underline yourString)
Available Chars (111)
---------------------
```

Comment: You probably meant `map (const '-')`

Comment: I suspect that this use of pointfree style is beyond the OP's ability; this answer would have been more helpful in pointful style, and by focusing on how `replicate` works.

Answer (score 4):

got it!

```
replicate n 'charHere'
```

for example, if you want to repeat the char `'-'` 12 times:

```
replicate 12 '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to (re)implement `replicate`, for instance as follows,

```
replicate' :: Int -> a -> [a]                
replicate' n x = if (n <= 0) then [] else (x : replicate (n-1) x)
```